# Android comand line tools avdmanager error

Tags: android

Running the following avdmanager command produces the following error:

```
/usr/local/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/avdmanager -v create avd -n "test" -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a" --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a
```

Error:

```
Error: Exception during AvdManager initialization
Error: null
expected a non-null reference
```

We are currently migrating from Java 8 to Java 11 and this command used to work before under Java 8 (OpenJdk). I have gotten the latest command line tools from Google

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-8512546_latest.zip
```

Java version

```
# java --version
openjdk 11.0.14 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This problem occurs if I run any avdmanager command

```
/usr/local/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/avdmanager -v list
```

Local Path

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/android-sdk/tools:/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/30.0.3:/usr/local/android-ndk
```

Android Home

```
# echo $ANDROID_HOME
/usr/local/android-sdk
```

However the sdkmanager commands work fine

```
/usr/local/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager --no_https --install "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
```

Any thoughts on why this cryptic message shows up? Usually the errors are more descriptive and this has left my stumped for now.

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: We fixed it by having both Java 8 and 11 installed together. Using Java 8 for the avdmanager commands and Java 11 for the gradle compilation is what works for us. Hopefully this gets fixed by Google in the future. :)